# What is the optimal way to deploy Java AWS Lambda?

Tags: java, aws-lambda

There are two approaches of "deploying" a Java Lambda:

- create a "fat" jar including all (unpackaged) dependencies, e.g. by use of the maven-shade-plugin
- create a zip file containing my code and a lib directory with all dependencies as jar files

As it takes really long until the environment that executes our simple Lambda is "booted" (20-30s), I wonder if either approach is "faster" than the other or can be further speed up?

Comment: I have only tried the fat jar approach and I can think that one is faster as there are less files to unzip... but you can try that out and test it for yourself ;). I honestly don't think that either approach will be noticeable faster, but you can try.

Comment: I've deployed many "Fat jar" lambdas using the Maven shade plugin, most start in < 200ms depending on the lambda size, and subsequent executions run in < 100ms.

You need to look at the following. Your lambda  size? I've seen good performance using the 1024mb tier. What is going on when you start your application. Are you running spring or something?

Comment: Tried both approaches, didn't notice a difference.
However, I can distinguish 3 different behaviours: Initial ramp-up of 20-30 "instances" in parallel to deal with the events (~150-250/minute) causes "boot times" of 30s+; regular event processing takes less than 100ms; in the following hours there are some isolated "boot events" that take ~5s.

Comment: @djhworld: only old school java stuff.
I use the AWS SDK to decrypt credentials using KMS, then access a RDS MySQL. The latter seems to take ~3s for the first time and could explain the 5s "boot events".

Comment: Lambda will kill your JVM occasionally so you'll see some Lambda invocations needing to start it up again

Comment: @skirsch if you're accessing RDS when it first loads up you might see some delay there yeah. We do something similar in ours but with dynamoDB to read some configuration. This is done with Google Guice so it only happens once when the JVM process is started.

Comment: @djhworld Just out of curiosity, I removed the database access. Still, I experience enormous instantiation times when several instances are created. However, the scattered instance creations only take 1-1.5s now, so that's notably less. Wonder if the KMS interaction also takes some one-off creation time on client or server side...

Comment: @skirsch do you have an example available of this project (maybe github)? (I'm specifically interested to see how you've done the zip approach...)

Comment: @eugenevd unfortunately I don't have the zip-solution available anymore.
I suspect to have used the https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin to create the zip file...

Answer (score 4):

I have found that the FAT jar is the optimal approach for lambdas with a footprint smaller than the MB limit.  If you are over the MB limit, add the libraries to the lambda's lib folder and read them in.

With jars in the lib, I have found is that the lambda loads a little slower when it launches the first time in a container... the first time it is slower, subsequent launches in the same container are very fast... if it goes to a new container, one-time slow again.

Here is some good info on those cold starts: 
https://hackernoon.com/im-afraid-you-re-thinking-about-aws-lambda-cold-starts-all-wrong-7d907f278a4f